# Drools wants Java compiler, which is not present in custom image

Tags: drools, optaplanner, jlink, jpackage

All,

I have my optaplanner application using JavaFX. Running and testing it in IntelliJ's IDE was not the problem, but generating an application from it was really painful. Mainly due to the combination of the (modular) JavaFX modules with other non-modular libraries : JavaFX is modular, my application isn't (nor is optaplanner). So I had to generate a custom JRE including the JavaFX modules, **and only then**, using that custom JRE, build my application using that runtime. I was quite helped in this (and its integration in maven) by this link : https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX . Generation of my application succeeded, and I can execute it.

But. My application, upon clicking a problem(/solution) file, processes that file to display the score. So drools pops in. And drools apparently wants the java compiler. Only 1 problem : my application's JRE (in the custom image generated during the build) doesn't include one. So I receive the following error message (/exception) :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompilerException: Cannot find the System's Java compiler. Please use JDK instead of JRE or add drools-ecj dependency to use in memory Eclipse compiler
```

Adding that drools-ecj dependency to my project's pom.xml hasn't fixed the problem. Adding the option --bind-services to jlink seems to work, but I want to avoid having to generate too big an application image. I could probably include an extra module in my custom JRE, but I lack the knowledge to figure out which one. So my question : how could I get this issue solved ?

Comment: I would just try the relevant ones from this list one by one: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/index.html There don't seem to be that many candidates.

Comment: You could run `jdeps --print-module-deps` on the library jars.

Comment: @JornVernee In the script (see the link I referred to), there already was $JAVA_HOME/bin/jdeps -q --multi-release ${JAVA_VERSION} --ignore-missing-deps --print-module-deps --class-path "target/installer/input/libs/*" target/classes/be/mydomain/optaplanner/buiten/app/App.class

So for some reason, this dependency was missing in the result of jdeps. No clue why that can have been, however...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that will actually find all the dynamic dependencies. Whether a dynamic dependency (such as a service impl, or class accessed through reflection) is required depends on the implementation of the library. I think your best bet is probably to contact the library authors and ask which module are required (if it's not specified somewhere already).

Comment: As @JornVernee already said, it is impossible to find all dependencies via some static analysis because Java has reflection. There is no other proof than a 100% test of your app.

Comment: @mipa : ... unless maybe making the optaplanner framework modular ?

Comment: @sudo No, you have the same problem in a modular setup. There are even more stumbling stones then.

Comment: I'm sorry to come back on this, but due to a script mistake, in a previous comment I had erroneously stated that java.instrument was fixing my issue. It isn't (fixing it). It worked thanks to the jlink's option "--bind-services" (that I wanted to avoid using ...). I deleted my erroneous comment to avoid confusion...

Comment: The missing module was jdk.compiler

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a ConstraintProvider, upgrade to OptaPlanner 8.24 or later and switch to `constraintStreamType=BAVET` (see docs how to), to avoid needing Drools.

We did a similar trick to get OptaPlanner running on Android.